# Targeting specific child component in cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am adding test todo during cypress test and I want to remove it in test which triggers after one adding it. How can I target it so I can do click() action only on remove button of this test todo? The one that I have below doesn't seem to target removing icon of testing todo but targets all of them in the document.

```
describe("App test", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("localhost:3000");
  });

  /* ==== Test Created with Cypress Studio ==== */
  it("adding todo test", function () {
    /* ==== Generated with Cypress Studio ==== */
    cy.get('[data-testid="mainPage-addTodoBtn"]').click();
    cy.get('[data-testid="task-input"]').type("Test");
    cy.get('[data-testid="name-input"]').type("TestUser");
    cy.get('[data-testid="deadline-input"]').click().type("2022-11-25");
    cy.get('[data-testid="description-textarea"]').click();
    cy.get(".sc-hAZoDl").click();
    /* ==== End Cypress Studio ==== */
    cy.get('[data-testid="AddTodo-form-wrapper"]').should(($p) => {
      expect($p.last()).to.contain("Successfully added Todo");
    });
  });
  it("removing todo test", () => {
    cy.get('[data-testid="main-page-todos-wrapper"]')
      .first()
      .get('[data-testid="remove-icon"]')
      .click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

after `first()`, you have to chain with `.find('[data-testid="remove-icon"]')` not with `.get('[data-testid="remove-icon"]')`.
see difference [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Get-vs-Find)